# With which symbol can I replace anyInt in "expected should equal("""anyInt - anyInt - anyInt""")"

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito, scalatest

I want to check if a date has the format "yyyy-MM-dd".
date should equal("""anyInt-anyInt-anyInt""").

With which symbol should I replace anyInt in java?

Comment: you should read up on regex

Comment: Thank you... "expected shouldBe regex"? And then equal to what?

Comment: no ... myFormattedDate.matches(regexPattern) or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex: `\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}`

`\\d` matches any digit (exactly one)

`{x}` is number of occurrences

`\\d{4}` => matches four digits

`\\d{2}` => matches two digits

etc.

`\\d+` => matches unlimited number of digits (at least one)

`\\d*` => matches unlimited number of digits (zero or more)